# ipython shell syntax error with "?" in string in `python-shell-send-string`

Tags: python, doom, ipython

When in the IPython shell, `?open` returns help on the "open" function. But when I send it with `python-shell-send-string` it throws a syntax error saying "?" is not recognised. I can see the output in the IPython shell. I am using Doom Emacs. The default Python shell is set to "python3". I've tried changing it to "ipython3", didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the python evaluation set-up code. It throws the syntax error as it needs a valid python syntax and "?" is IPython command line specific. I found a couple of functions that would send a string directly to the interpreter:
`comint-redirect-send-command` and `comint-redirect-send-command-to-process`.

These do the job pretty well.

Edit:

I've just come across the following. One can run IPython specific commands from script (or as a send string) using the following command.

```
get_ipython().run_line_magic('pinfo2', 'object')
```

This is equivalent to running `object??` in the IPython console. `pinfo` is equivalent to `object?`.